# Trigger an aws-amplify build via aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I am creating a aws-amplify app via aws-cdk and everything works fine except it doesn't start a build automatically. If I do a git commit (I have enabled continuous deploys) it will build and run just fine. But on a new aws account with a cdk deploy I have to start the first commit manually...

Comment: As stated [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9479) it not possible via cdk

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue as well while working on the deployment of an amplify hosted application.

After going through the AWS CLI documentation for Amplify, I found the [start-job](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/amplify/start-job.html) command. This command allows you to start an amplify job for a specific branch.

You can then create an `AwsCustomResource` that makes an SDK call to start-job.

This is what I ended up with.

```js
const build_trigger = new customResource.AwsCustomResource(this, 'triggerAppBuild', {
    policy: customResource.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
        resources: customResource.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE
    }),
    onCreate: {
        service: 'Amplify',
        action: 'startJob',
        physicalResourceId: customResource.PhysicalResourceId.of('app-build-trigger'),
        parameters: {
            appId: amplifyApp.appId,
            branchName: master.branchName,
            jobType: 'RELEASE',
            jobReason: 'Auto Start build',
        }
    },
});
```

Note that you should replace `amplifyApp.apiId` and `master.branchName` with your own app ID and branch name. I am using the amplify-alpha, so you may need to get the App ID and branch name another way.

Answer (score 0):

Amplify app builds are triggered by push events.  Use a CDK [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) or its simpler cousin [Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html) to generate a push event during the CDK stack creation.

For a github repo, for instance, your `Trigger` construct's lambda would call the Github webhook test API, which [will trigger the hook with the latest push to the current repository](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/webhooks#test-the-push-repository-webhook).  Both Custom Resources and Triggers can be configured to run only on stack creation.  Remember to give your lambda any necessary repo credentials (e.g. set environment variables via a secret).